# MySQL one-to-many conditional query using only 2 queries - Why MyBatis does not use this? Is it bad?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Suppose the classical sample: Two tables `blogs` and `posts`, and they are `one-to-many`. We want to know the blogs satisfying some condition (`SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE my_condition`) and all `posts` associated with them.

My way:

1. `SELECT blog_id, some_other_blog_columns FROM blogs WHERE my_condition`. Then extract all information, and also save all blog_ids into an array, say `List<Integer> blog_ids`.
2. `SELECT post_id, blog_id, some_other_post_columns FROM posts WHERE blog_id IN (?,?,...,?)` with the `?` being plugged in by the `List<Integer> blog_ids`.

Then only 2 queries are needed and everything is running with index, so isn't it fast?

---

On the other hand, I think MyBatis' JOIN method has some cons. The method: `SELECT blog_id, post_id, some_other_blog_columns, some_other_post_columns FROM blogs OUTER JOIN posts WHERE my_condition`. Cons:

1. `some_other_blog_columns` are repeated `k` times if one blog on average corresponds to `k` posts. Bad when those columns are big, then we are wasting bandwidth and CPU.
2. Need to perform `JOIN`, which is slow and consume precious CPU on the server.

---

So I wonder why MyBatis uses that? And is my method better?

Thanks for any reply!

Comment: An outer join doesn exist in mysql Only  Left or right, so which is it? Inner Joins they are quite fast, as long yoz have indexes on the ON column, and the inner join would remove row. An outer join can't remove rows so it os slower that inner join, but i would prefer the join method IN CLAUSE wouldn-'t be that much faster.

Comment: @nbk From MyBatis: `... from Blog B
  left outer join Post P on B.id = P.blog_id
  where B.id = #{id}` https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html

Comment: @nbk Oh really? I will try to make some speed test! However, what about the 1st con - wasting bandwidth when big column? Thanks!

Comment: Your way (using `(?,?,...,?)`) will run as long as you don't reach driver limits. You cannot use 10000 values on a list. The driver will impose some limits and the query will crash.

Comment: @TheImpaler Good reason, thanks! However, are my two cons for the MyBatis approach correct or not? Thanks!

Comment: The first one is definitively correct, though in my experience hasn't happened very often. The second one, no; the join can be pretty performant even with high number of rows, if you have the right indexes.

Comment: @nbk By the way I have heard that big companies never use `JOIN`, but instead do it on the client side. Is it true?

Comment: @TheImpaler Thanks very much for the reply! By the way I have heard that big companies never use JOIN, but instead do it on the client side... So maybe I have heard some rumor...?

Comment: @fzyzcjy I don't think that's generally true. There may be some very specific cases when that may happen. I've only seen it in cases where the mainframes are so overwhelmed by massive number of rows that programs must resort to such esoteric alternatives. But no, in general JOINs are quite efficient.

Comment: @TheImpaler Thanks for the information! By the way, I wonder what order of magnitude are talking about -- for instance, my situation will have 10million blogs and 1000million posts at least

Comment: Just to be clear, you can use the first approach with MyBatis. MyBatis just executes the SQLs you write. Now, if there are 10 million blogs and 1000 million posts, neither 1 nor 2 performs well, I imagine. I would consider retrieving a certain number of blogs first (like 1000 or 5000) preferably by specifying a range of indexed column (e.g. `id between 1 and 1000`) rather than by specifying `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`. Then get posts for each blog while looping the blogs. It requires much less memory and it matters more than the number of queries when there are that many rows.

Comment: @fzyzcjy 'My way' obviously won't work because it may exceeds the number of max placeholders as TheImpaler pointed out. However the JOIN approach might work if you use [Cursor](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/java-api.html). You should give it a try.